# How can I put the contents of a iframe inside the iframe's container?

Tags: html, css

How can I put content of a iframe to be inside borders of iframe's container?

```
<div id="kontejner">
<iframe style="z-index:-5;" src="somesource.html" width="1200px" height="200px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Where `#kontejner` is 700px wide?

Comment: Did you inspect elements? you can do this easily by changing the src property of the iframe.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have tried?

Comment: How about `#kontejner {overflow: hidden}`?

Comment: Thank you, that allmost resolved my problem, now it looks more better, thank you.

Comment: I resolved it, thank to your advice, and a little trick of adding a vertical bar to hide part of incoming picture. Thank you once more.Now it seems like this:http://gimnazijapancevo.freehostia.com/a_primeri_koda/okvir11.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is make the container scroll. You can do that with:

```
#kontejner { overflow-x: auto }
```